# Select last non-NA value in a row, by row

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame where each row is a vector of values of varying lengths.  I would like to create a vector of the last true value in each row.

Here is an example data frame:

```
df <- read.table(tc <- textConnection("
   var1    var2    var3    var4
     1       2       NA      NA
     4       4       NA      6
     2       NA      3       NA                
     4       4       4       4              
     1       NA      NA      NA"), header = TRUE); close(tc)
```

The vector of values I want would therefore be `c(2,6,3,4,1)`.

I just can't figure out how to get R to identify the last value.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: +1 for creating reproducible data

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do this by combining three things:

- Identify `NA` values with `is.na`
- Find the last value in a vector with `tail`
- Use `apply` to apply this function to each row in the `data.frame`

The code:

```
lastValue <- function(x)   tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1)

apply(df, 1, lastValue)
[1] 2 6 3 4 1
```

Comment: Sweet!  I knew there must be a function for this: tail.  Many thanks--marked as answered!

Comment: or, more elegant `apply(df, 1, function(x) { tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1) })`

Comment: is that more elegant or just more compact?  I think I like Andrie's solution better (it's too bad `tail` doesn't have an `na.rm` argument, then you could just do `apply(df,1,tail,n=1,na.rm=TRUE)` ...

Comment: That doesn't seem more elegant to me.  It's fewer lines but otherwise the exact same thing.  I should think elegance would refer to a better algorithm, better expression of the existing one, or some function that accomplishes the task more simply.  One liners like that tend to look cluttered and confusing, especially to novices... remembering back to being a novice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer using matrix subsetting:

```
df[cbind( 1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df),"last") )]
```

This `max.col` call will select the position of the last non-NA value in each row (or select the first position if they are all NA).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version that removes all infinities, NA, and NaN's before taking the first element of the reversed input:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) rev(x[is.finite(x)])[1] )
# [1] 2 6 3 4 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr alternative is to use `coalesce` and reverse the order of the selected columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  mutate(var5 = coalesce(var4, var3, var2, var1))

#   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
# 1    1    2   NA   NA    2
# 2    4    4   NA    6    6
# 3    2   NA    3   NA    3
# 4    4    4    4    4    4
# 5    1   NA   NA   NA    1
```

To make use of `tidy`selection, one can create an auxiliary function `coacross` to use `coalesce` with `across`, and use `rev` to reverse the order of the names:

```r
coacross <- function(...) {
  coalesce(!!!across(...))
}

df |> 
  mutate(var5 = coacross(rev(everything())))
```