# Select last value in a row & place it in another column

Tags: r

I have data table like this

```
Col1 | Col2 | Colx
 12  |  13  | 19
 34  |  NA  | NA
 13  |  33  | NA
```

to determine the last value in each row I used Andrie's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532639/select-last-value-in-a-row-by-row) for a previous question on the same subject

But I'd like the output to be in a separated column, the expected output for the above example.

>

```
Column
  19
  34
  33
```

The OG question in the link above didn't solve my problem, as the output is not coming in a new column.

Comment: `df$Column <- apply(df, 1, function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot but how to make the output in a separated column?

Comment: What do you mean by "separated"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select last value in a row, by row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532639/select-last-value-in-a-row-by-row)

Comment: @VincentGuillemot thank you, u made a great help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))
```

If you want the result in a new column, you can do:

```
df$newColumn <- apply(df, 1, function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))
```

Comment: but I want the result to be in a separated column

Comment: I even didn't followed the link! Do `df$newColumn <- apply(...)` if you want a new column.

Comment: relax jogo. the reason I thought it's copies because I saw the same code and it gives me the same exact output which I don't want. the output is not coming in a new column, its saved as a VALUE in R.

Comment: @RayanSp : And what happens to `df` once you run the command `df$newColumn <- apply(df, 1, function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))`?

Comment: @Rayan R don't know about **column** or **row** in the case of a vector. You have to interpret the direction of the vector for yourself (or simply not to thing of the direction of the elements).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
i1 <- which(!is.na(df1), arr.ind=TRUE)
unname(tapply(df1[i1], i1[,1], FUN=tail,1))
#[1] 19 34 33
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(12, 34, 13), Col2 = c(13,
NA, 33), Colx = c(19, 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", "Colx"), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I get this error when run the second column " i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657"

Comment: @RayanSp I assumed that you have a `data.frame`

Comment: By doing `unname(tapply(as.data.frame(df1)[i1], i1[,1], FUN=tail,1))`, you can rid of this error.