# Find last non-missing value per row

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I have a dataframe with a variable `var` that was measured at time points 0 to 2. Like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id= letters[1:5],
                 var0= c(1:3, NA, 5),
                 var1= c(11, NA, NA, 14:15),
                 var2= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 25))
df
  id var0 var1 var2
1  a    1   11   NA
2  b    2   NA   NA
3  c    3   NA   NA
4  d   NA   14   NA
5  e    5   15   25
```

For each row, i.e. for each person, I want to keep the newest non-missing value. So the desired output is:

```
  id var0 var1 var2 last_val
1  a    1   11   NA       11
2  b    2   NA   NA        2
3  c    3   NA   NA        3
4  d   NA   14   NA       14
5  e    5   15   25       25
```

How to do this within the tidyverse packages?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532639/select-last-non-na-value-in-a-row-by-row

Comment: @mt1022 Thank you. I can solve this one in base, but not in tidyverse slang ;)

Comment: To be fair your title/question does not state you want a specific tidyverse answer. @Maël did give one thought . It might be smart to add Tidyverse, as that seems to specify your question.

Comment: @Omniswitcher Was part of tags, but I edited the question slightly to make more clear. Maybe it will help someone in future. All the best

Answer (score 7):

You can use `coalesce`. The trick is to reverse the order of the variables in `coalesce` so that it returns the last non-NA value in the real data:

```r
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  mutate(last_val = coalesce(var2, var1, var0))

#   id var0 var1 var2 last_val
# 1  a    1   11   NA       11
# 2  b    2   NA   NA        2
# 3  c    3   NA   NA        3
# 4  d   NA   14   NA       14
# 5  e    5   15   25       25
```

If you want to make use of [`tidy` selection](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html), you can define a `coacross` function first, and then `rev`erse the order. More about using `across` with `coalesce` [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/funs/issues/54).

```r
coacross <- function(...) {
  coalesce(!!!across(...))
}

df |> 
  mutate(last_val = coacross(rev(contains("var"))))
```

Answer (score 5):

An R base alternative:

```
> df$last_val <- apply(df, 1, \(x) tail(na.omit(x), 1))
> df
  id var0 var1 var2 last_val
1  a    1   11   NA       11
2  b    2   NA   NA        2
3  c    3   NA   NA        3
4  d   NA   14   NA       14
5  e    5   15   25       25
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single-line dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, last_val = coalesce(var2, var1, var0))
```

Result:

```
  id var0 var1 var2 last_val
1  a    1   11   NA       11
2  b    2   NA   NA        2
3  c    3   NA   NA        3
4  d   NA   14   NA       14
5  e    5   15   25       25
```

As we were almost simultaneous with @Maël giving our first solution(s)
here is another option:

```
  df %>% 
    mutate(last_val = apply(.[,-1], MARGIN = 1, \(x) do.call(coalesce, as.list(x[length(x):1]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized using `max.col`:

```
df$last_val <- df[,-1][cbind(1:nrow(df[,-1]), max.col(!is.na(df[,-1]), "l"))]
df
#>   id var0 var1 var2 last_val
#> 1  a    1   11   NA       11
#> 2  b    2   NA   NA        2
#> 3  c    3   NA   NA        3
#> 4  d   NA   14   NA       14
#> 5  e    5   15   25       25
```

Answer (score 0):

A trick with `left_join` + `pivot_longer`

```
df %>%
    left_join(
        (.) %>%
            pivot_longer(!id, values_to = "last_val") %>%
            na.omit() %>%
            slice_tail(n = 1, by = id) %>%
            select(!name)
    )
```

gives

```
  id var0 var1 var2 last_val
1  a    1   11   NA       11
2  b    2   NA   NA        2
3  c    3   NA   NA        3
4  d   NA   14   NA       14
5  e    5   15   25       25
```